# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‐ not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, packages, unicode

I am using BibTex for referencing and when I added a new reference I got the following error message: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‐ not set up for use with LaTeX., which seems to occur at the line where I have \usepackage{setspace}. There seems to be a problem with the dash character (-), which is in one of the titles of a reference I am using. I am using the MacTex editor. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: if `inputenc` is set to `utf8`, try `utf8x` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had the current version of latex (or the one before) then it would work by default, but for older releases you can just define the needed character

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}
```